# Join one table with two other ones by id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join one table with two others that are unrelated to each other but are linked to the first one by an id

I have the following tables

```
create table groups(
 id int,
 name text
);

create table members(
 id int,
 groupid int,
 name text
);

create table invites(
 id int,
 groupid int,
 status int    \\ 2 for accepted, 1 if it's pending
);
```

Then I inserted the following data

```
insert into groups (id, name) values(1,'group');
insert into members(id, groupid, name) values(1,1,'admin'),(1,1,'other');
insert into invites(id, groupid, status) values(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(3,1,1);
```

Obs:

- The admin does not has an invite
- The group has an approved invitation with status 2 (because the member 'other' joined)
- The group has two pending invites with status 1

I am trying to do a query that gets the following result

```
groupid | name  | inviteId
1       | admin | null
1       | other | null
1       | null  | 2
1       | null  | 3
```

I have tried the following querys with no luck

```
select g.id, m.name, i.id from groups g
left join members m ON m.groupid = g.id
left join invites i ON i.groupid = g.id and i.status = 1;
```

```
select g.id, m.name, i.id from groups g
join (select groupid, name from members) m ON m.groupid = g.id
join (select groupid, id from invites where status = 1) i ON i.groupid = g.id;
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `members` and `invites` are not related, you need to use two separate queries and use `UNION` (automatically removes duplicates) or `UNION ALL` (keeps duplicates) to get the output you desire:

```
select g.id as groupid, m.name, null as inviteid from groups g
  join members m ON m.groupid = g.id
union all 
select g.id, null, i.id from groups g
  join invites i ON (i.groupid = g.id and i.status = 1);
```

Output:

```
 groupid | name  | inviteid 
---------+-------+----------
       1 | admin |         
       1 | other |         
       1 |       |        3
       1 |       |        2
(4 rows)
```

Without a `UNION`, your query implies that the tables have some sort of relationship, so the columns are joined side-by-side.  Since you want to preserve the `null` values, implying that the tables are not related, you need to concatenate/join them vertically with `UNION`

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)